# Session handling using Python Requests client

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, web-scraping, session

I'm using this code to login to an experiment login system created by me for this purpose.

```
import requests
import re

def get_page_data(regex, req):
    match = re.compile(regex).search(req.text)
    if match != None:
        return match.group(1)
    return 'no match found on {}'.format(regex)

def print_req_data(req, req_name):
    print('{} status code: {}'.format(req_name, req.status_code))
    print('{} title: {}'.format(req_name, get_page_data('<title>(.*?)</title>', req)))
    print('{} content:\n{}'.format(req_name, req.text))

form_url = 'http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/'
post_url = 'http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/process.php'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    # get form page, so the cookies are set (form token)
    logged_out_req = s.get(form_url, headers=headers)
    print_req_data(logged_out_req, 'Logged out request')
    title_logout = get_page_data('<title>(.*?)</title>', logged_out_req)
    # getting the form token
    token = get_page_data('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="(.*?)">', logged_out_req)
    login_data = {'password' : 'password', 'username' : 'miguel', 'token': token}
    # posting the data to the post url
    post_req = s.post(post_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print_req_data(post_req, 'Post request (redirect page)')
    check_post_title = get_page_data('<title>(.*?)</title>', post_req)
    # comparing the titles (logged out title with redirect page title) so i see if login success
    if(check_post_title != title_logout):
        print('SUCCESS\n[+] Checking if still logged in...')
        # going to see if i'm still loggin, see if our loggedin session is permanent
        logged_req = s.get(form_url, headers=headers)
        print_req_data(logged_req, 'Check if still logged request')
        title_check = get_page_data('<title>(.*?)</title>', logged_req)
        if(title_check == check_post_title):
            print('You are still loogedin')
        else:
            print('Not loggeding anymore')
    else:
        print('FAIL LOGIN')
        print_req_data(post_req, 'Post request (redirect page)')
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, especially with regard to:

1. Is there a better way to get the form token? I tried checking the headers,

   ```
   logged_out_page = s.get(form_url, headers=headers)
   print(logged_out_page.headers) # headers the server sent back to us
   print(logged_out_page.request.headers) # headers we sent to the server
   ```

I know that [session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) values are not stored on our machine (browser) unlike normal cookies, those are stored in the server so the real session value is not on the headers (just some id key to the server, so it can fetch the real data stored on it). But is there anyway besides using regex to extract the session value? PS: (session cookie produced with php, `$_SESSION['token] = md5(time())`).

2. Is there a way (besides doing a string comparison of the page title, or some other element on the page) to check if the login was successful?

Any other comments and suggestions are, of course, welcome. If you'd like to test this code (python3, using the links above, `form_url` and `post_url`) with the username `miguel` and the password `password`.

PS: Bear in mind that this code is based on the loggedin system mechanic that I created (the most usual, i guess). I don't wish any improvements on this code based on another

Comment: can you please stop editing your code? It makes it hard for someone to review the code if you keep changing it.

Comment: I edited yesterday @Dannnno

Comment: Yes, and I started reviewing yesterday only to find that some of your changes invalidated parts of my review

Comment: Sorry @Dannnno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Please don't use regexes

Regular expressions are power tools. You can use them for many situations, but they tend to be inherently fragile. They're especially fragile for parsing HTML, in part because of how lenient most browsers will be. I'd recommend using a dedicated parser for it.  If you decided that since this is a page you control you don't need to be that careful that's fine, just be aware.

#### `main`

You shouldn't execute any code in the main body of your program - anything that should execute should be inside of an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, and that should still be broken up into functions for ease of use.

#### `get_page_data`

Don't return a value if nothing was found; this would be very unexpected (and it would be annoying to check for, with a few edge cases). Instead raise an appropriate exception.

You also don't need to do `if match != None:`, just do `if match:`

```
class NoMatchFoundException(Exception): pass

def get_page_data(regex, req):
    match = re.compile(regex).search(req.text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    raise NoMatchFoundException("No match found on {}".format(regex))
```

#### Favor good names over comments

Comments are almost always a sin. A necessary sin, but they mean that you haven't been able to sufficiently express yourself in code. Most of your comments would be great function names, e.g.

```
# get form page, so the cookies are set (form token)
logged_out_req = s.get(form_url, headers=headers)
print_req_data(logged_out_req, 'Logged out request')
title_logout = get_page_data('<title>(.*?)</title>', logged_out_req)
```

becomes

```
def get_form_page(session, url, headers):
    return session.get(url, headers=headers)

def get_page_title(page):
    return get_page_data('<title>(.*?)</title>', page)

logged_out_req = get_form_page(s, form_url, headers)
logout_page_title = get_page_title(logged_out_req)
```

Also you desperately need whitespace - add newlines liberally to group like sections of code. This is also a good way to see where you should create a new function.

I've left out the printing, because...

#### Don't print willy nilly

Most of the time you have a bunch of print statements they are intended to be debugging output; remove that before you actually use this. Occasionally if you need some sort of admin script or you need to know the status that's fine, but make sure you're printing out the bare minimum of what you need, and a log file is still going to be better.

I ended up with something like this. A lot of the functions end up not doing a whole lot, and if you don't think they're adding a lot of value remove them - the point of them, however, is to make it clear what each step is intended to do.  You'll note that I never do any error handling - I don't know what you actually want to be doing when the match fails.

```
import requests
import re

class NoMatchFoundException(Exception): pass

def get_page_data(regex, req):
    match = re.compile(regex).search(req.text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    raise NoMatchFoundException("No match found on {}".format(regex))

def get_page_title(page):
    return get_page_data("<title>(.*?)</title>", page)

def get_page(session, url, headers, data=None):
    data = data if data else {}
    return session.get(url, headers=headers, data=data)

def print_req_data(req, req_name):
    print('{} status code: {}'.format(req_name, req.status_code))
    print('{} title: {}'.format(req_name, get_page_title(req)))
    print('{} content:\n{}'.format(req_name, req.text))

def get_form_token(page):
    return get_page_data('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="(.*?)">', page)

def logged_in(logout, logged):
    return get_page_title(logout) != get_page_title(logged)

def same_page(first, second):
    return get_page_title(first) == get_page_title(second)

def test_login(form_url, post_url, headers, username, password):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        logout_page = get_page(s, form_url, headers)

        form_token = get_form_token(logout_page)
        login_data = {'password' : password, 'username' : username 'token': form_token}

        logged_in_page = get_page(s, post_url, headers, login_data)

        if logged_in(logout_page, logged_in_page):
            logged_in_test = get_page(s, form_url, headers)

            if same_page(logged_in_test, logged_in_page):
                print('You are still logged-in')
            else:
                print('Not logged-in anymore')
        else:
            print('FAIL LOGIN')
            print_req_data(post_req, 'Post request (redirect page)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    form_url = 'http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/'
    post_url = 'http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/process.php'
    headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}
    username = 'miguel'
    password = 'password'

    test_login(form_url, post_url, headers, username, password)
```

Comment: Another thing could be to have some default headers

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. It seens you did't test your code. Where are you posting (post method to the `post_url`) the data to form? You have some errors, and after correcting them i couldn't login

Comment: @Miguel you're correct, I did not. I often don't for code review questions, because if you're just taking what I write and copy it verbatim then that isn't helping anyone; it's more about concepts. I just include the fully rewritten code for completeness and as a reference. If I get a chance I'll come back and tweak it.

Comment: Thanks @Dannnno. I understood what you're saying and your reviews